# Pandas 'values' converts pd.Timestamp to datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with columns of type `pandas.Timestamp`, which I need to convert to a list of lists (list for each row). When I use `df.values` I do get a list of lists, but the type is converted to `datetime64` which causes problems later in my code. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')]).values
Out[259]: array([['2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

If I use `pandas.Series.to_list` on each column separately, the type is kept:

```
pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')])[0].to_list()
Out[261]: [Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

But if I have multiple columns it becomes inconvenient, as I need to apply it to each column and using `zip` to get a list of lists of Timestamps.

Is there a more direct way of getting the values without this type conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to_dict method specifying the orient as list

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ { 'a' : pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01') , 'b' : pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')}]  )

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
           a          b
0 2020-01-01 2020-01-01

In [56]: list(df.to_dict('list').values())
Out[56]: [[Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')], [Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')]]
```

Comment: Great! exactly what I needed.